# PHP/MySQL different value for each row

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched and I've tried many different things but I haven't been able to come up with anything to work the way I want.  What I have is a direct message system but I want to show next to the users name how many new messages they have from that person if it's more than 0.  Everything I've tried just shows one value for all of the conversations.  In my database I have a column that is if the user who received the message read it, if they had it turns the 'no' into a 'yes', otherwise it shows 'no'.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** 
One thing for my database...Only the first message in the conversation has both the `to_id` and `from_id` after that all the other messages in the conversation only has the `from_id`.  So what I'm trying to do is count how many where the `from_id` is not your `user_id`, so the non-signed in user user_id.  If that makes sense.

Here is my code accessing the database:

// Get the conversations

```
$get_conversations = "SELECT dm.convo_id, dm.message_id, dm.to_id, dm.from_id, dm.user2read, u.name, u.user_id" .
                    " FROM users u" .
                    " JOIN direct_messages dm" .
                    " ON dm.from_id = u.user_id" .
                    " OR dm.to_id = u.user_id" .
                    " WHERE u.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
                    " GROUP BY dm.convo_id" .
                    " LIMIT 1";



// Run the conversation query
$convo_result = mysql_query($get_conversations);
```

And then some HTML code
And more php in the body tags

```
<?php
while ($teg = mysql_fetch_array($convo_result)) {
    if($teg) {
        $to_id2 = $teg['to_id'];
        $from_id2 = $teg['from_id'];


        if($from_id2 == $_SESSION['user_id']) {
            $id_of_other_person = $to_id2;
        } else if($from_id2 != $_SESSION['user_id']) {
            $id_of_other_person = $from_id2;
        }

        // Get the name of the other person
        $get_other_name = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $id_of_other_person;

        // Run the query on the other person's name
        $query_name = mysql_query($get_other_name);
        if($query_name) {
            $yelp = mysql_fetch_array($query_name);
            $name_of_other_person = $yelp['name'];
        }

        $get_user2read = "SELECT dm.convo_id, dm.message_id, dm.to_id, dm.from_id, dm.user2read, u.name, u.user_id" .
                        " FROM users u" .
                        " JOIN direct_messages dm" .
                        " ON dm.from_id = u.user_id" .
                        " OR dm.to_id = u.user_id" .
                        " WHERE u.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
                        " AND user2read = 'no'" .
                        " GROUP BY dm.convo_id" .
                        " LIMIT 1";



        $query_user2read = mysql_query($get_user2read);
        $alg = mysql_fetch_array($query_user2read);

?>

<?php if(COUNT($alg['user2read']) > 0 && $alg['user2read'] == 'no') : ?>

<h3>You have <?php echo COUNT($teg['user2read']); ?> new messages - from <a href="#"><?php echo $name_of_other_person; ?></a></h3>
<?php else : ?>



<?php endif; ?>

<?php

}

}
?>
```

I would post in image of my direct_messages table but I don't have enough reputation...
Here is a diagram of my table:

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    convo_id    bigint(20)          No          
    message_id  int(11)         No          
    to_id   int(11)         No          
    from_id int(11)         No          
    message varchar(5000)   latin1_swedish_ci       No          
    timestamp   timestamp           No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       
    user1read   varchar(3)  latin1_swedish_ci       No          
    user2read   varchar(3)  latin1_swedish_ci       No
```

EDITED: I erased the backslashes

Comment: Sidenote: There's no mention of `session_start();` anywhere. You are using it, right? ;-) If not, then you must include it inside all your pages.

Comment: Plus this and other similar looking `($alg\['user2read'\])` the way you're placing the backslashes, that doesn't seem right to me. If you're trying to escape the quotes, you need to do `\'`

Comment: Yes I'm using session_start();  And I did not put the backslashes in the code, it was pasted in when I pasted the code, for some odd reason.  I edited and deleted the backslashes

Comment: Why do you have `LIMIT 1`, but then you have a `while` loop over the results? Don't you want to return all the user's conversations?

Comment: The query that I have the `LIMIT 1` is not in a `while` loop.  I have the first `SELECT` statement to get the conversations and then I was using the second one to get the number of new messages where `user2read = 'no'`

Comment: You have LIMIT 1 in both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
<h3>You have <?php echo COUNT($teg['user2read']); ?> new messages - from <a href="#"><?php echo $name_of_other_person; ?></a></h3>
```

`count()` is used for arrays, but the elements of `$teg` are just the column values from the table. If you want to count records grouped by a column, you need to use the MySQL `COUNT()` function in your query. Or in this case, since you only want to count messages that fit a specific criteria, use `SUM()`:

```
$get_conversations = "SELECT dm.convo_id, dm.message_id, dm.to_id, dm.from_id, u.name, u.user_id, SUM(dm.user2read = 'no') unread_count" .
                    " FROM users u" .
                    " JOIN direct_messages dm" .
                    " ON dm.from_id = u.user_id" .
                    " OR dm.to_id = u.user_id" .
                    " WHERE u.user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'] .
                    " AND dm.user2read = 'no' " .
                    " GROUP BY dm.convo_id" .
                    " LIMIT 1";
```

Then you can use `$teg['unread_count']` to get the count of unread messages in that conversation.

I don't think you need the inner query `$get_user2read`. All the information is in `$get_conversations` now. It was wrong, because it wasn't getting the row specific to the conversation in that iteration of the loop.

Comment: I get an internal server error when I replace $get_conversations with this one, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Okay, that helped me out.  The problem I'm having now is that it's only showing one conversation

Comment: Did you see my comment above? Why do you say `LIMIT 1` if you want more than 1 conversation?

Comment: Yeah, I got rid of the `LIMIT 1` and now I have three conversations that all say 2 new messages.

Comment: I wonder why you're returning fields like `dm.message_id` in the query. Since you're just returning one row for each conversation, that will just pick a random message ID from the conversation. What's the point?

Comment: That's wrong, the first conversation should be 0, the second one should be 2, third one should be 1.  And I need to get the first `message_id` because that's the only one that has both the `to_id` and `from_id`.  I just edited the question

Comment: If you want the first message ID, you should say `MIN(dm.message_id)`.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: I tried making one, but I got an error, here's the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c63a/2

Comment: And I'm able to get the first message_id it's just I can't get the number of new messages.

Comment: You can't put PHP variables in sqlfiddle, duh!

Comment: Or PHP concatentation. Just ordinary SQL.

Comment: I get the correct answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c63a/4 But there's only one conversation.

Comment: That makes sense.  And I updated the fiddle to have two conversations.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b745/1 The problem is that in my table after the first message only the `from_id` gets filled in, the `to_id` is left blank. I will adjust that so that it fills in the `to_id` when a new message is sent.  I want to get the number of new messages that are sent to me, not ones that I sent, if that makes sense.

Comment: Change the argument to `SUM()` to specify the criteria you want to count. E.g. `SUM(user2read = 'no' AND to_id = user_id)` will only count the number of unread received messages.

Answer (score 0):

This 
`$yelp = mysql_fetch_array($query_name);
$name_of_other_person = $yelp\['name'\];` 
looks wrong.

You need to loop the $yelp like you did $teg.

Comment: That works for me, I'm able to get the name of the sender, the problem I'm having is that I can't get how many new messages there are for each conversation

Comment: That's what I'm using `<?php echo COUNT($teg['user2read']); ?>` for, to get the number of new messages but it only shows the same number for each one